# How would I prove $\cos{\frac{n\pi}{3}}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that $a_n=\cos{\frac{n\pi}{3}}$ diverges using the definition:

> A sequence $a_n$ diverges if $\forall L\in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists \varepsilon>0$ s.t. $\forall N$,
> $\exists n\gt N$ s.t. $|a_n-L|\ge \varepsilon$

I think this inequality is true:
$$-L-1\le |\cos{\frac{n\pi}{3}}-L|\le L+1$$

So if I let $\varepsilon=-L-1$ then $|a_n-L|\ge \varepsilon$ but $\varepsilon \gt 0$ so I probably can't do this. I'm not sure choosing an $n$ is valuable just because the cosine function is limited to $[-1,1]$

Comment: Better prove it has subsequences converging to distinct limits. Compute the first values of your sequence and see it is periodic.

Comment: Notice that $\cos \frac{n\pi}3$ only takes the same four values over and over again.  As the same values are always  certain distance apart we can't find any $L$ that is always within that distance.  $\cos \frac {6n\pi}3=0$ and $\cos \frac {(6n+1)\pi}3 = \frac 12$.  So if we take $\epsilon = \frac 14$ we are done.  If $L$ is within $\frac 14$ of $0$ then $\cos \frac {(6n+1)\pi}3=\frac 12$ is more than $\frac 14$ away.  And if $L$ is within $\frac 14$ of $\frac 12$ then $\cos\frac{6n\pi}3=0$ is more than $\frac 14$ away.

Comment: Notice if $n\equiv 0\pmod 6$ then $\cos\frac {n\pi}3 = 1$.  And if $n\equiv 3\pmod 6$ then $\cos\frac{n\pi}3 = -1$.  Let $\epsilon =1$.  Is there any possible number $L$ where $|1-L| < 1$ and $|-1 -L|< 1$ are *BOTH* true? (ALso note that for any $N$ we can always for some $n > \frac N6$ so $6n > N$ and $6n +3 > N$.)

Comment: Are you concerned with $\cos(n\pi/3)$ or $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \cos(k\pi/3)$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite absolutely not. I'm disappointed anyone would ***completely change*** the question based on that assumption

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence is
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,\ldots\right\},$$
(the sequence repeats itself after $1$).
Notice that each possible value is at least $1/2$ apart from the others. Take any $L\in\mathbb{R}$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Fix $\epsilon_0:=1/2$. Can you find $n>N$ such that the distance from $L$ to $a_n$ is greater or equal to $1/2$?

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way is find an explicit formula for the partial sum from $n=1$ to $n=m$ and then look at the limit as $m \rightarrow \infty$. Use the forward difference notation $$\Delta F(n)=F(n+1)-F(n)$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^m \Delta F(n)=F(m+1)-F(1).$$ Use $$F(n)=\sin((n-1/2)\pi/3)$$ and divide by $2\cos(\pi/6)$, which is a constant.